# Are implications transitive for validity question?

Tags: logic

I have the following two premises.

1. If it's Monday, I work out
2. If I work out, I take an evening shower

It's Monday, thus I take an evening shower.
Is this statement valid? I'm pretty sure it is since the way premises 1 and 2 are phrased Monday and an evening shower should be linked by transitivity. Is that accurate for logic?

Comment: This is known as [Hypothetical Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) as a mode of inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. While the truth-functional operator $\to$ (called the ‘material implication’ or ‘material conditional’) used in truth-functional logic does not always match our intuitions with regard to ‘if … then …’ conditionals used in real life (see ‘Paradoxes of Material Implication’), it does match our intuition that the ‘if … then …’ should be transitive. That is, in truth-functional logic you can infer $P \to R$ from $P \to Q$ and $Q \to R$. Probably the easiest way to see this is with truth-table.